# AngularJS adding extra option to zend select

Tags: angularjs, select, zend-framework2, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to use angular to post content from a zend form into a modal and it keeps adding an extra option at the top that has blank text and value="? Number 3 ?"

I see a number of threads that are saying this is because the ng-model is not yet set, but I have verified the value I'm using (a property of an object) is set already and has a value that is one of the valid select options.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out as I was posting it, but figured I would post the answer since I didn't see it in any of the other threads. My object in the javascript is apparently smarter than Angular or at least Angular is smarter than Zend.

Zend is creating the options with the id's for the select options in quotes, thus they are appearing as strings. The property of the object has is initialized as an integer and apparently angular is too smart to compare them as equal.

Forcing the property to a string in the scope seems to have corrected the issue. e.g.

```
listsApp.controller(
'EditListController',
[
    '$scope', '$element', '$rootScope', '$http', 'title', 'list', 'close',
    function ($scope, $element, $rootScope, $http, title, list, close) { //ngDialog
        $scope.title = title;
        $scope.list  = list;

        // angular fails on zend string option values if id is an integer
        $scope.list.ListtypeId = '' + list.ListtypeId;

        $scope.origTypeId   = $scope.list.ListtypeId;

        // ....
}
```